# Android Custom Toolbar centering with back/menu buttons

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-constraintlayout

I thought this would be a simple task but oh Android, why is this so hard :facepalm:

I have this custom Toolbar layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    ....width/height stuff>
    <ConstraintLayout
      ....width/height stuff>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            ...start_toStartOf="parent"
            ...end_toEndOf="parent"
            ...top_toTopOf="parent"
            ...bottom_toBottomOf="parent">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello World!"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ContstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This works fine if I don't put HomeAsUpButton or a menu item(s).

This screenshot shows how it's not centered when I put a back button
[image]

This back button is not part of my Toolbar layout because I want my toolbar implementation to be as 'raw' as possible.

Back button is added by

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

and it pushes my layout to right.

**Q: Is there any way I can ignore left button or menu buttons that will be added to the right, and center the TextView? Do I really have to hack it and make my own Left Button/menu-like layout?**

If my question is unclear, please let me know and I'll elaborate.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just wondering. Why does this question deserve a negative vote? What does it lack?

Comment: I have the same problem  didn't fix mine +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your `Toolbar` XML code with this:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:theme="@style/toolbarTheme">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/textPrimary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_toolbar"
            tool:text="Title" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Also set properties:

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: looks like `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)` was not necessary but making TextView a direct child of the Toolbar worked fine.. now I have to find a way to enable Title and Subtitle together. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To remove the automatic added paddings the back button adds you can simply just add the following attributes to the toolbar:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but inset solves a different from what I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display `TextView` in the center of Toolbar you should not use default back button and menu because `ToolBar` like horizontal `LinnerLayout` where you layout always will be between back button and menu view.

`[[ arrow ][     your layout     ][ menu items ]]`

You have two way haw to display text in the horizontal of toolbar:

1. All the time when you change something in `ToolBar` you must find middle of toolbar and manual put text in position `middle - (text.width / 2)`
2. Create custom layout where you put text in the center of layout.